# Terraform AutoScaling group module user data: Unable to pass shell script with variables

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, terraform

I am building AWS infrastructure with Terraform and need to pass a shell script that has variables into the user data of a launch template. This is how I am referencing the script which is in a variable:

```
 **user_data_base64          = filebase64(var.aws_userdata)**
```

This is one of the errors I am getting:

```
**Error: Variables not allowed
│ 
│   on variables.tf line 345, in variable "s1_aws_userdata":
│  345:         source /tmp/${CURL_FILEPATH}
│ 
│ Variables may not be used here.**
```

Is it possible in Terraform to accomplish this? Here is the variable with the script:

```
variable "s1_aws_userdata" {
  type = "string"
  default = <<EOF

#!/usr/bin/env bash


function download_and_run_scripts {

    echo
    # dependency check
    if [ ! -x /usr/bin/curl ]; then
        echo -e "Error, curl is not installed."
        exit 1
    fi
    # s1g_install scripts
    local DOWNLOAD_SCRIPTS="toolkit.sh ${AMI_SCRIPTS}"
    local CURL_FILEPATH=""
    for CURL_FILEPATH in ${DOWNLOAD_SCRIPTS}; do
        echo -e "\nGoing to download: ${CURL_FILEPATH}\n"

        case ${CURL_FILEPATH} in
            toolkit.sh)
                local CURL_REPO="s1_tools"
                ;;
            *)
                local CURL_REPO="s1g_install"
                ;;
        esac

        local CURL_TOKEN="xxxx"
        local CURL_OWNER="xxx"
        local CURL_URL="xxxxx"

        /usr/bin/curl --header "Authorization: token ${CURL_TOKEN}" --header "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw" \
          --location ${CURL_URL} -o /tmp/${CURL_FILEPATH} --silent
        if [ ! -f /tmp/${CURL_FILEPATH} ]; then
            echo -e "Error, unable to download ${CURL_FILEPATH} file."
            exit 1
        fi
        chmod +x /tmp/${CURL_FILEPATH}
        source /tmp/${CURL_FILEPATH}
    done
}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Define here scripts (separated with 1 space) that will be executed on first run:
AMI_SCRIPTS="s1_ami_base_lynis.sh"
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
download_and_run_scripts
EOF
}
```

Comment: It's saying there is an error with `s1_aws_userdata` but you don't show the code that uses a variable with that name. What you are trying to do is certainly possible, but you need to provide more information so we can see exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Hi @MarkB, thank you for your reply. I have just added the variable with the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your script variable references look just like Terraform interpolation syntax, Terraform doesn't know how to deal with it. You need to [escape](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html) the variables in the shell script using double dollar signs `$$`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Mark! That did the trick.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey Mark, although it worked I am getting  this now:

Error: Invalid function argument ; this function works only with files that are distributed as part of the configuration source code, so if this file will be created by a resource
│ in this configuration you must instead obtain this result from an attribute of that resource.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `filebase64()` on a string variable. Just remove the call to that function completely, and pass the variable directly.